# Grab parameters in abstract methods

Tags: java, parameter-passing, functional-interface

I am attempting to create an Object that servers like a `Runnable`, but accepts certain input and delays. This will later be incorporated into a Timer I'm making as a personal project, but that's besides the point.

I want to keep track of the parameters when they are initialized, however, `abstract` methods are, well, `abstract`, and if I were to replace it with a normal method, it would lose it's purpose to be like a `Runnable` accepting certain parameters and interaction.

Currently, everything other than the parameters seems to be doing fine, all I need to do is figure out how to keep track of them.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Task {

    AtomicLong delay = new AtomicLong(0);

    default long getDelay() {
        return delay.get();
    }

    default void setDelay(long milliseconds) {
        delay.set(milliseconds);
    }


    void execute(String... parameters);

    default Runnable wrap(String... parameters) {
        return () -> execute(parameters);
    }
}
```

My other thought was that I could possibly develop an event to catch when it happens, however after further research, I learned it wasn't that simple.

Worst case scenario, I create getters and setters, however that would make it more difficult to utilize them in the way I envisioned, and overall, the aesthetics would be poor when viewed by another source.

Comment: I suspect that this may be a possible XY Problem type question, but having said that, what matters with interfaces are behaviors and behaviors only, and not state. If you need the parameters to be "retrievable"then you need to give the interface appropriate getter methods

Comment: how retrieval is implemented is no concern of the interface itself

Comment: You could create an array (or List, Set, Table, etc) in the abstract class to store the variables.